# md5sum value changes every time I compile cuda source code

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, macros, timestamp

I was trying to verify if my macro really works during compilation by md5sum command in ubuntu.

For example, by "nvcc -DTEST_MACRO ...." I got an executable A. 
Then by "nvcc ..." I got an executable B. 
Of course the md5 values are different.
**But, I recompiled and generated A again. Its md5 is different from previous one.**

I took a pure c++ code and checked with g++, and its md5 value turns out to be the same no matter how many times I compiled. So I think there is something like time stamp in the executable generated by nvcc.

- Just out of curiosity, how do I verify if my thought is right?
- Anyway, how do I verify if "TEST_MACRO" really works in this case?

Comment: I don't know if this will help with your problem, but it's a pretty good article on the kinds of things you might need to do with GCC to generate deterministically identical output (even though you say that this isn't a problem for you with g++): http://blog.mindfab.net/2013/12/on-way-to-deterministic-binariy-gcc.html  The issues and techniques discussed in the article might be helpful to you finding a solution for nvcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this variability is not necessarily due to an embedded timestamp, but rather by the way `nvcc` builds executables.

`nvcc` is a compiler-driver, meaning it launches a sequence of commands "under the hood" to compile code.  During the execution of this sequence, a variety of temporary files are created with randomly-generated filenames.  You can get a sense of this by looking at the output of your `nvcc` compile command with the `-v` switch added.

Some of these filenames *do* get embedded in the executable, and since these randomly-generated file names vary from one invocation of the `nvcc` compile command to the next, the resultant binary will vary.

If you want to verify this yourself, run your `nvcc` command with `-v` added.  Then inspect the output at the end for a `tmpxft...` filename.  Then grep the generated executable for that filename, eg.:

```
grep tmpxft_0000a76e myexe
```

(replace the `tmpxft_0000a76e` with whatever appears in your `nvcc` verbose output, and replace `myexe` with the actual name of your executable.)

If you want to verify if a TEST_MACRO really works, there are a few options.  The least intrusive might be to put the following line in your TEST_MACRO body:

```
#ifdef TEST_MACRO
...
#warning TEST_MACRO_COMPILED
...
#endif
```

and you should see this echo'ed to the output during compilation, when you specify  `-DTEST_MACRO`

(The above is a useful technique to avoid mistakenly including debug macros and other things you don't want in a production/release build of code.)

Of course, there are probably many other possibilities.  If the test macro includes executable code, you could put a `printf` statement in it, to see evidence at run-time.

Comment: 0000a76e in this example is the hex-encoded nvcc PID.

Comment: @OrivejDesh How do you know this is the nvcc PID?  I don't see that documented anywhere.  We also needed to make nvcc deterministic and resorted to hex editing the tmpxft string inside the binary.

Comment: It is undocumented. I was looking for the causes of nondeterminism, noticed that this value in particular was generally increasing, but remains a small constant in a new PID namespace.Later I found that I can eliminate the tmpxft string altogether by running nvcc with --keep.

Comment: Note that if you need nvcc --device-c & --device-link, it has another source of nondeterminism: when .cpp has no exported symbols, the output depends on the modification time of the source and the current working directory.
Our final solution is in https://github.com/catboost/catboost/commit/f39838c3